# Ajax method working twice in a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-ajax

The file upload function working on the Upload button click.The function

```
$("#fuPDFAdd").change(function () {})
```

file upload change is working two time when click the 'btnUploadAdd' button.
How can avoid this

```
<div id="divUploadFileAdd">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="frmUplaodFileAdd">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <input id="fuPDFAdd" name="file" type="file" style = "display:none;"/> 
        <button class="" id="btnUploadAdd" type="button" onclick="test()">Upload</button>
        <label id="txtuploadedMsgAdd"> </label>
    </form>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#fuPDFAdd").change(function () {
        console.log("tst1");
        var file = this.files[0];
        fileName = file.name;
        size = file.size;
        type = file.type;
        if (type.toLowerCase() == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet") { //I just want pdf files and only want to show
            var formData = new FormData($('#frmUplaodFileAdd')[0]);
            $.ajax({
                url: "UploadFile",  //Server script to process data
                type: 'POST',
                async: false,
                xhr: function () {  // Custom XMLHttpRequest
                    var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                    if (myXhr.upload) { // Check if upload property exists
                        myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',
                        progressHandlingFunction, false); // For handling the progress of the upload
                    }
                    return myXhr;
                },
                data: formData,
                //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    grdStaffAddition.PerformCallback({ transStatus: "New" });
                    ShowClientToastr('False', 'False', 'toast-bottom-right', 'True', 'success', 'Template migration completed' + data.result, 'CAM - Contract Staff');
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            ShowClientToastr('False', 'False', 'toast-bottom-right', 'True', 'error', 'Please select xls/xlsx file.', 'CAM - Contract Staff');
        }
    });
});

function test() {   
    $("#fuPDFAdd").click();
}
```

Comment: `$("#fuPDFAdd").click();` or  `("#fuPDFAdd").change();` ?

Comment: You have to provide minimalistic sample replicating your issue

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work, I did wrap the file upload code to a separate function there, and make it to call this new function from your event listeners.

```
function uploadTheFile() {
    console.log("tst1");
    var file = this.files[0];
    fileName = file.name;
    size = file.size;
    type = file.type;
    if (type.toLowerCase() == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet") { //I just want pdf files and only want to show
        var formData = new FormData($('#frmUplaodFileAdd')[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: "UploadFile", //Server script to process data
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            xhr: function() { // Custom XMLHttpRequest
                var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                if (myXhr.upload) { // Check if upload property exists
                    myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',
                        progressHandlingFunction, false); // For handling the progress of the upload
                }
                return myXhr;
            },
            data: formData,
            //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data) {
                grdStaffAddition.PerformCallback({
                    transStatus: "New"
                });
                ShowClientToastr('False', 'False', 'toast-bottom-right', 'True', 'success', 'Template migration completed' + data.result, 'CAM - Contract Staff');

            }
        });
    } else {
        ShowClientToastr('False', 'False', 'toast-bottom-right', 'True', 'error', 'Please select xls/xlsx file.', 'CAM - Contract Staff');

    }
}
$("#fuPDFAdd").change(function() {
    uploadTheFile();
});

function test() {
    uploadTheFile();
}
```

Comment: Actually the code `function test() {   
    $("#fuPDFAdd").click();
} ` is working for fileupload dialog window open instead of file upload control and upload button usage